# JavaFX tableView not populating, can't see mistake

Tags: javafx

I can't figure out why my TableView is not setting the data. Seemingly everything is ok, but the rows just won't appear. i looked through tutorials, but I still don't see my error.Here is my code.
The data class:

```
package model.elastic;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class ElasticAttribute {

private SimpleStringProperty name;
private SimpleStringProperty type;
private SimpleStringProperty variable;

public ElasticAttribute(String name, String type, String variable) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.type = new SimpleStringProperty(type);
    this.variable = new SimpleStringProperty(variable);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getType() {
    return type.get();
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type.set(type);
}

public String getVariable() {
    return variable.get();
}

public void setVariable(String variable) {
    this.variable.set(variable);
}

}
```

The controller:

```
@FXML
private TableView<ElasticAttribute> tableView;

private TableColumn tableColumnName;

private TableColumn tableColumnType;

private TableColumn tableColumnVariable;

public void initialize() {

    final ObservableList<ElasticAttribute> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new ElasticAttribute("Test", "Test", "Test"),
            new ElasticAttribute("Test2", "Test", "Test"),
            new ElasticAttribute("Test3", "Test", "Test"),
            new ElasticAttribute("Test4", "Test", "Test"),
            new ElasticAttribute("Test5", "Test", "Test")
    );

    tableColumnName = new TableColumn("Name");
    tableColumnName.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ElasticAttribute, String>("name"));
    tableColumnType = new TableColumn("Type");
    tableColumnType.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ElasticAttribute, String>("type"));
    tableColumnVariable = new TableColumn("Variable");
    tableColumnVariable.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ElasticAttribute, String>("variable"));
    tableView.setItems(data);
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumnName, tableColumnType, tableColumnVariable);
```

The fxml:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've shared, so my guess is the problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps you are recreating a TableView, so the one you see is not the one you access in `initialize`? 
Providing the relevant parts of the code (any mention of `tableView`, your FXML etc. ) could help.

Comment: Is there anywhere else in the controller you access `tableView`? Do the column headers appear, or are they as well absent?

Comment: nowhere else..., the column headers appear

Comment: ooooh damn, actually I did access it: bindBidirectional(tableView.itemsProperty(), element.listProperty()); and this made the elements not appear